# How to upload 6000 record to Google Datastore from csv file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html is not clearly understand. Where i should call the bulkloader.py or appcfg.py? Should i import the csv file to local Google App Engine SDK first? How to keep the upload and download data process in existing application for datastore synchronization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set Up remote_api, the docs have [instructions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) for both java and python and then run bulkloader.py locally :

```
bulkloader.py --dump --app_id=<app-id> --url=http://<appname>.appspot.com/remote_api --filename=<data-filename>
```

if you are using the java sdk, you will need to install the python sdk.

Comment: run bulkloader.py locally means in the SDk interactive console (http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/interactive), its first time to do so ...

Comment: That's right, open a command terminal and run the bulkloader script, if you are using the java sdk, you will need to install the python sdk.

Comment: Thanks in advance Iggy. I'm using phyton SDK. The Console keep saying like this ...: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\admin\__init__.py", line 209, in post
    compiled_code = compile(code, '<string>', 'exec')
  File "<string>", line 1
     bulkloader.py --dump --app_id=myapp --url=http://myapp.appspot.com/remote_api --filename=myapp
                                                                ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Ivan No, run it from a command line, not from the SDK console.

Comment: Yeah Thx Iggy... i'm runing it on CMD (Command Prompt). All records successfully uploaded.